# C++: Giving value to array of chars

Tags: c++, concatenation, arrays

So I have this:

```
char uloginName[] = "derp";
char mew[33] = "home/home/" << uloginName << "\0";
```

I am trying concatinate uloginName with the rest of the string that will later be converted to an array of char. But it keeps returning me an error. I don't know how to do it.
Also, I must use only char[] type as of this moment; No string.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `"\0"` and `""` are equivalent; you should null-terminate with `mew[upper_bound] = '\0'`.

Comment: You have several answers that tell you to use strcat/strncat, and they are correct.  But they don't explain why what you're doing generates an error.  You mistook the integral type "char" for a class that defines the << operator (like cout).  But the char data type is not a class.  It's an integral type that doesn't understand the << operator.

Comment: Thanks @CareyGregory, that truly helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char uloginName[]="derp";
char mew[33]="home/home/";
strcat(mew, uloginName);
```

You can use `strcat` on arrays of characters, so long as there is sufficient space and they are terminated with a zero byte.

Comment: So should I say `char uloginName[]="derp\0";` instead?

Comment: That's redundant. When you write `"derp"`, you've already specified a C-style string with a zero terminator. If you print `sizeof(uloginName)`, you'll see it's 5 already. You could also do `{'d','e','r','p','\0'}` if you want.

Comment: Thank you, also, I think `strcat()` is for strings only. I am working with char type right now for which I am using `strncat()`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Your character arrays contain C-style strings. A "string" just means that it's terminated by a zero byte. Unless you separately track the lengths, you'll have to use the fact that their strings too -- otherwise how will you know how many bytes to work with?

Answer (score 2):

Use [strncat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/), which is a versatile and far less error-prone way of handling strings in C++. `strcat()`, `strncat` and their kin are hangovers from `C` and should be used cautiously in C++.

```
char uloginName[] = "derp";
std::ostringstream mew;
mew << "home/home/" << uloginName;
```